# How to adjust table cell with depend on longest one with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am implementing table layout with flexbox but I got a problem. If I use `table` tag for it, it is easy to adjust cell width but with Flexbox, it is not easy. Please tell me how to adjust cell width depends on longest one and should I use `table` tag instead of flexbox ?

Table:

```
| id    | text        |
| ----- | ----------- |
| 3     | lorem lorem |
| 43432 | lorem lorem |
```

Flexbox:

```
| id | text        |
| -- | ----------- |
| 3  | lorem lorem |
| 43432 | lorem lorem |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are working with?

Comment: this looks like tabular data so you could use `table` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I understand you are displaying tabular data. In this case, you have two options

1. Responsive layout? Use `divs` with `display:table|table-row|table-cell`.
2. Same table for all devices? Use the classic `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`'s...

Flexbox is for layout-ing. It's supposed to flex depending on "cell" contents. It's for fluid, linear content.